# 2.79 - Blurry artifacts with BDSF Glass Shader

Tags: shaders

[image]

I get some blurry artifacts on a glass shader in my very simple setup (see image1).

2 meshes, smoothed with SubD (2) modifier : glass container on the outside (mesh1, image2), coffee or other liquid in the inside (mesh2, image3).

[image]

[image]

Principled BDSF on both meshes.IOR around 1.3-1.4 and transmission near to 1 (0.99).Normals are ok. Meshes are overlapping.

Lightning : world (white, strength : 1.5)

When mesh2 is outside from mesh1, problem seems to disappear.

Level of SubD has no effect on the artifact.

When i rotate the view around the object, artifacts stay at the same place.

When i modify the IOR of the glass shader, artifacts become bigger or smaller.

So, what could it be ?

Comment: Could you share the blend file to help us replicate the problem?

Comment: Is your inner objects surface completly inside the glass volume of your outer object? I think maybe there is some polygon not completly inside. Try checking that with Shift+F in solid mode.

Comment: Here's the file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oi6X9mh8KxlW_djqt_Td7yc3pcnuZTSz

Comment: Ok, i get the artifacts when the roughness of the BDSF Glass shader is between 0.1 and 0.3 approximately. Their position changes depending on the roughness value.